# OWIN Web API + OWIN Test Server + Ninject Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-web-api2, ninject, owin

From a high level perspective, I would like to use the OWIN Test Server to perform integration testing on Web API controllers that I have created. I am roughly following this tutorial by [David Whitey](http://www.davidwhitney.co.uk/Blog/2015/01/07/testing-an-asp-net-webapi-app-in-memory/). Here is the technology stack overview

**OWIN**

- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.OWIN.Testing
- Other Owin components for self hosting

**Ninject**

- Ninject.Web.WebAPI.OwinHost
- Other relevant Ninject Web API components

**Moq**

- Used for mocking service classes in my controllers

The overall application functions very well - Web API Controllers + OWIN + Ninject, but when I go to create Integration Tests using the OWIN Test server, I have not found a way to rebind my mocked services. This is due to the Ninject service provider - the scope of the Ninject Kernel is set on a per request basis, therefore I cannot rebind a Mocked service to the request.

One method I have discovered around this (see **ConfigWebAPIForIntegrationTesting()** below)   is to set a dependency resolver on the Http configuration as opposed to using the Ninject Owin extension **UseNinjectWebApi()**. This would work great but when I implement this, it doesn't appear that Ninject is able to pick up the Web API binding as it normally would with **UseNinjectWebAPI**

At this point I'm pretty stuck. In a world of sunshine and rainbows, I would like to be able to create integration tests in my test project, using the OWIN Startup.cs from the concrete implementation and swap out business logic service classes as necessary. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions to righting my dependency injection woes and successfully unit testing my Web API endpoints?

Many thanks in advance for all help on this question!

**Startup.cs - In Blog.UI Project**

```
public partial class Startup
{
    #region Ninject Dependency Injection
    private static IKernel _container { get; set; }
    public static IKernel Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (UseUnitTestKernel)
            {
                return _container;
            }

            throw new Exception("Startup has not been designated to use integration test dependeny injection");
        }
    }
    public static bool UseUnitTestKernel { get; set; }
    #endregion Ninject Dependency Injection

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    //Save off _app builder in case we want to retrieve a value later
    private static IAppBuilder _app;


 /// <summary>
    /// Bootstrap application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        _app = app;
        ConfigureAuth(app);

        if (!UseUnitTestKernel)
        {
            app.UseNinjectMiddleware(NinjectWebApiKernel.CreateKernel);
            app.UseNinjectWebApi(ConfigWebAPI());
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseWebApi(ConfigWebAPIForIntegrationTesting());
        }
    }

        /// <summary>
    /// Configure authorization
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        PublicClientId = "JustBlogWeb";

        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/Account/Authorize"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });




        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
    }

        /// <summary>
    /// Setup WebAPI routes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private HttpConfiguration ConfigWebAPI()
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Web API configuration and services
        //Must have this on to view errors;
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Just Blog API")).EnableSwaggerUi();

        return config;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure Web API for integration testing
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private HttpConfiguration ConfigWebAPIForIntegrationTesting()
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Web API configuration and services
        //Must have this on to view errors;
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        _container = new StandardKernel();
        _container.Bind<DefaultModelValidatorProviders>()
                        .ToConstant(new DefaultModelValidatorProviders(
                                config.Services.GetServices(typeof(ModelValidatorProvider)).Cast<ModelValidatorProvider>()));

        _container.Bind<DefaultFilterProviders>()
            .ToConstant(new DefaultFilterProviders(
                    config.Services.GetServices(typeof(IFilterProvider)).Cast<DefaultFilterProvider>()));

        //_container.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly().SelectAllClasses().BindAllInterfaces());
        _container.Bind<IPostService>().To<PostService>();
        config.DependencyResolver =  new NinjectUnitTestDependencyResolver(_container);

        return config;
    }
```

**Ninject Dependency Resolvers - in Blog.UI project**

```
    /// <summary>
/// Static class for generating a Web API Ninject Kernel
/// </summary>
public static class NinjectWebApiKernel
{
    //List of Mocked Services
    public static IDictionary<Type, Mock> Mocks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create kernel bindings for IoC and Dependency Injection
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        RegisterServices(kernel);

        //Rebind mocked services if we have any
        // TODO Remove rebind and extraneous ninject rules
        //RebindToConfiguredMocks(_container, Mocks);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Register ninject services
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel"></param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IAuthProvider>().To<AuthProvider>();
        kernel.Bind<IJustBlogContext>().To<JustBlogContext>();

        kernel.Bind<IPostService>().To<PostService>();
        kernel.Bind<ICategoryService>().To<CategoryService>();
        kernel.Bind<ITagService>().To<TagService>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rebind all mocked services for dependency injection
    /// </summary>
    private static void RebindToConfiguredMocks(IKernel kernel, IDictionary<Type, Mock> mocks)
    {
        foreach (var item in mocks)
        {
            kernel.Unbind(item.Key);
            var item1 = item;
            kernel.Bind(item.Key).ToMethod(_ => mocks[item1.Key].Object);
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Ninject Unit Testing Dependency resolver. We use this dependency resolver
/// for unit testing
/// </summary>
public class NinjectUnitTestDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
{
    protected IResolutionRoot Container;

    public NinjectUnitTestDependencyResolver(IKernel container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public NinjectUnitTestDependencyResolver(IResolutionRoot container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return Container.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return Container.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
    {
        if (!(Container is IKernel))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Can't begin a scope on a scope");
        }

        return new NinjectUnitTestDependencyResolver(((IKernel)Container).BeginBlock());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

**Test Class PostController_Tests - In Blog.UI.Tests project**

```
    public class PostController_Tests
{
    private TestServer _server;
    private const string _baseServerURL = "http://testserver";
    private IDictionary<Type, Mock> _mocks;

    /// <summary>
    /// Integration test for the Post Controller "UnitTest" endpoint
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task PostController_UnitTest_Test()
    {
        string endPoint = $"{_baseServerURL}/{RoutePrefixes.RESOURCE_POST}/{nameof(PostController.UnitTest)}";

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _server.HttpClient.GetAsync(endPoint);

        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.AreEqual(content, "true");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Test the retrieval of a post by url tag
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task RetrievePost_By_UrlTag_Test()
    {
        string endPoint = GenerateAPIEndpoint(RoutePrefixes.RESOURCE_POST, nameof(PostController.Retrieve));

        var postSet_Mock = new Mock<DbSet<Post>>();

        var justBlogContext_Mock = new Mock<JustBlogContext>();
        justBlogContext_Mock.Setup(m => m.Posts).Returns(postSet_Mock.Object);

        IPostService postService = new PostService(justBlogContext_Mock.Object);

        MockOut<IPostService>().Setup(x => x.Post(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new PostViewModel());

        HttpResponseMessage response = await _server.HttpClient.GetAsync(endPoint);
        PostViewModel result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<PostViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run after the entire test class runs
    /// </summary>
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void ServerInit()
    {
        _mocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Mock>();
        Startup.UseUnitTestKernel = true;

        _server = TestServer.Create<Startup>();

        var test = Startup.GetTestKernel();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Run before each class is initialized
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    [TestCleanup()]
    public void ServerDispose()
    {
        _server.Dispose();
    }

    #region Private Methods and Classes

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate the API endpoint for a controller method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="controllerName"></param>
    /// <param name="methodName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected string GenerateAPIEndpoint(string controllerName, string methodName)
    {
        return $"{_baseServerURL}/{controllerName}/{methodName}";
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new mocked service
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected Mock<T> MockOut<T>() where T :class
    {
        if (_mocks.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            RebindToConfiguredMocks();
            return (Mock<T>)_mocks[typeof(T)];
        }

        _mocks.Add(typeof(T), new Mock<T>());
        RebindToConfiguredMocks();

        return (Mock<T>)_mocks[typeof(T)];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Rebind all mocked services for dependency injection
    /// </summary>
    protected void RebindToConfiguredMocks()
    {
        foreach(var item in _mocks)
        {
            Startup.Container.Unbind(item.Key);
            var item1 = item;
            Startup.Container.Bind(item.Key).ToMethod(_ => _mocks[item1.Key].Object);
        }
    }

    #endregion Private Methods and Classes
}
```